# How do I transform this erb to haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

How do I transform this to haml?

```
<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
```

Comment: You can use http://html2haml.heroku.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
.alert{ class: "alert-#{name == :notice ? 'success' : 'error' }" }
```

Or maybe this looks neater:

```
%div{ class: "alert alert-#{name == :notice ? 'success' : 'error' }" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%div{:class => "alert alert-#{name == :notice ? 'success' : 'error' }"}
```

or, more cleanly:

```
- alert_type = name == :notice ? 'success' : 'error'
%div{ :class => "alert alert-#{alert_type}" }
```